# How are ACID properties provided in django transactions?

Tags: django, postgresql, transactions

If i want to write multiple SQL statements in a transaction block and make sure all the ACID properties are followed for that block, how should i achieve that?

Example - When i use **transaction.atomic**, it provides atomicity for that block of code but does it provide concurrency control and isolation (table level or row level)?

I'm currently using PostgreSQL and i've set **isolation level** to **ISOLATION_LEVEL_SERIALIZABLE**.

Does this provide me with serialized transactions for the **transaction.atomic** block?

And if doesn't do it so, how is it done?

Answer (score 3):

Django's `transaction.atomic` is implemented by using a database transaction, so whatever guarantees are provided by the database for its transactions will also be provided by Django's atomic blocks. So to answer your question, yes.

One subtlety to note, though, is that Django supports nested atomic blocks by using savepoints, and there is a difference between transaction blocks and savepoint blocks—specifically, a later exception within the same outer transaction will cause a successfully completed savepoint block to roll back.

Comment: Sorry, it took time to test this. transaction.atomic is just promising that either all or none of the queries under its block will run. No matter what i choose as the db settings.

Comment: @RA123: If you're having a problem I suggest you post a specific question about it and get help. All sorts of things in programming can go wrong and keep you from getting the results you expect. But you asked a very general question, and the answer is that Django implements `transaction.atomic` by using the transactions (and isolation levels) of the underlying database.